# Problem with model deforming exporting blender file (.fbx) into Unity

Tags: animation, export, import, unity

Ive tried a lot of different things to get this to work but I always end up with the same scenario.

I downloaded a mesh and made my own armature + animation.

When I export it (as .fbx) or simply drag the .blend file into unity, the model deforms.

Example pictures:

[image]

[image]

Everything looks great inside blender, but once it jumps into unity it deforms it.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Only Blender can handle its constraints. If you have Ik bones without targets and key all bones in the animation it will be right, but the complusions what made by the constraits won't work in other programs. So you have to create your animation without constraits or you have to export the files in FBX without "NLA Tracks" and "All actions". These options are located in the FBX exporter's Animation tab. Unfortunately in this case you can export only one animation per file.

Comment: @FFeller I removed all IK bones and tweaked the animations accordingly. It looks a lot better.
Thanks!